# Store data in an object format in a dictionary

Tags: python

Is there a way to store two list as a value for a key, but I want the lists to be represented in an object format, without having to actually create a class and build the object then store as a value.

For example, if the two list are : `[1,2,3,4]` and `['one','two','three','four']`, I would like the dict with a single key-value pair to be (`1` being the key):

```
{1: integer:[1,2,3,4], string:['one','two','three','four']}
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

If the dictionary is printed, I want to see the name of the attribute before the list, like this:

```
{1: {integer:[1,2,3,4], string:['one','two','three','four']},}
```

Comment: You could store a list of lists, or a dict. 

For example 

`{ 1: {"integer": [1,2,3,4],"string": ['one','two','three','four']} }`

Comment: From the question it is not apparent for me what you want to achieve. Can you add code how you would like to use that data structure? That might clarify the question.

Comment: You might be interested in the `dataclass` introduced in Python 3.7: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/dataclasses.html

Comment: What do you mean by "represented in object format", *everything is an object in Python*. Your example output is not valid python, and I can't understand what it's supposed to represent

Comment: Simply put, if I code the instruction print(dict[0]) after populating the dictionnary as explained in my example, I want the output to be: ```{"integer": [1,2,3,4],"string": ['one','two','three','four']}```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are several ways to get a value for a dictionary key with multiple items

```
>>> a,b=[1,2,3,4], ['one','two','three','four']
>>> {1:(a,b)} #use a tuple
{1: ([1, 2, 3, 4], ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'])}
>>> {1:[a,b]} #a list
{1: [[1, 2, 3, 4], ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']]}
>>> {1:{"interger":a,"string":b}} #a dict
{1: {'interger': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'string': ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']}}
>>> 
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> myvalue = namedtuple("myvalue","integer string")
>>> {1:myvalue(a,b)}
{1: myvalue(integer=[1, 2, 3, 4], string=['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'])}
>>> 
>>> from dataclasses import dataclass
>>> @dataclass
class myvalueclass:
    interger:list
    string:list

    
>>> {1:myvalueclass(a,b)}
{1: myvalueclass(interger=[1, 2, 3, 4], string=['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'])}
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dictionary concatenation. Ex :
`{ 1: {integer:[1,2,3,4] , string:['one','two','three','four']},}`

Comment: And how do you make sure when you print the dict, if shows the name of the attribute before the list like you are proposing? The format you wrote corresponds to what I'm looking for, but how do I have to add the entries to the dictionary to accomplish that.